# Reusing docker environment variables in CLI

Tags: docker, command-line-interface

Imagine having a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV HELLO_WORLD=hello
CMD echo $HELLO_WORLD
```

I'd like to reuse this variable from command line:

```
> docker build -t hello .
> docker run -e HELLO_WORLD='$HELLO_WORLD world' hello
$HELLO_WORLD world
```

I'd like this to result in `hello world` instead.

Now, I know I can do that in docker-compose and in Dockerfile but I wonder is there any chance to achieve this composition/reuse from CLI?

**Edit:**
So I was trying to achieve the same thing in docker-compose and I wasn't able to reuse variable from container

```
> cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  hello:
    image: 'hello'
    environment:
     - HELLO_WORLD="${HELLO_WORLD} world"

> docker-compose up hello
 world
```

It seems that only 2 places you can access the ENV from are the Dockerfile and then the executables/scripts running inside that docker image :(

Answer (score 0):

`ENV` directives are used at build time, not at runtime.

If you want to persist data, write it to a file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wasn't trying to persist data, I was trying to reuse the variable set in Dockerfile using ENV variable when setting new environment variable in docker CLI.